# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not running in AdHoc mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm testing my iOS app in AdHoc mode, and the following function in my `AppDelegate` doesn't seem to run in the AdHoc version of my app, despite working fine in development mode:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[@"noPush"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

This is supposed to create a new `Installation` object in the Parse database, and add it to the `noPush` channel. When I open the app for the first time, it doesn't do this, and the `channel` property shows up as undefined, as well as the `deviceToken` property. Does this need to be changed for production purposes? I was under the impression it worked regardless of what mode I was running it in.

Comment: have you updated the APN certificate for production?

Comment: I'm using a production APN certificate instead of development, if that's what you mean.

Comment: You should still have APN dev certificate for development purposes and Production certificate for release purposes. Let me know if that helps